# How do you pass html input text into a javascript function as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

My code is below. I would like the player to input their name into the html form and for this value to be submitted into the javascript scorecard class so that this.players = "name". How would I best do this? I have been trying to use jquery but am having no success.

**HTML:**

```
<section class="name1-2-12">
  <form class='name' action=''>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="NAME">
    <input type='submit' name='submit'>
  </form>
</section>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
var Scorecard = function() {
    this.players = 0;
};

Scorecard.prototype.addPlayer = function(name) {
  this.players = name
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The jQuery solution is nice, but a bit overdressed for the occasion.

Plain JavaScript:

You aren't really accustomed to JavaScript I guess:

```
var Scorecard = function() {
    this.players = 0;
};

Scorecard.prototype.addPlayer = function(name) {
   this.players = name
};
```

This code does two things:

1. It creates a constructor function called `Scorecard`. With this function you can create `instances` (simply put copies) of `Scorecard`.
2. You add a function to the `Scorecard` master object by using the prototype. Everything added via `prototype` will be shared by all instances of `Scorecard`

To sum this up. This isn't the way to go for the functionality you want. Consider this:

```
var Scorecard = function() {
    this.players = 0;
    this.playerList = [];  //create a new Array() using shorthand [];
    this.addPlayer = function(name)
    {
        this.players++; //add one to the player count.
        this.playerList.push(name); //add a player to the playerlist using array.push().
    }
};
```

What is this code doing:

1. It creates a master object called `Scorecard`.
2. A public variable is assigned called `this.players`. Public because it can be called upon outside the function `Scorecard`.
3. The same is done for the array: `this.playerList`.
4. A public `method` is added. Note this function only applies to the instance and is not shared with all instances.
5. The method `addPlayer` does two things. It takes name as argument. First it adds one to the public variable `this.players` by using `++`, which means add one. Secondly it adds a player to the array list by using the method `push`. Which appends an item to an array.

Now we need to create a submit event. When the user submits the form, a player is added to the Scorecard.

```
var scorecard = new Scorecard(); //first create an instance of Scorecard
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", formAddPlayer, false);

function formAddPlayer(e)
{
   e.preventDefault(); //e is the submit event. preventDefault stops it from actually posting the form, causing the page to reload.
   var name = e.target.querySelector("input[name='name']").value //get the value from the input element.
   scorecard.addPlayer(name);

   //show the results
   alert("Player amount: " + scorecard.players + "\nPlayers: \n -" + scorecard.playerList.join("\n -") ); //show the results
}
```

What is the code doing:

1. It creates a new instance (copy) of `Scorecard` named `scorecard`.
2. That instance has two properties: `players` and `playerList` and one method: `addPlayer`.
3. Attach an *onsubmit event* to the form. I used `document.querySelector` for this. Since your page only has one form, we can select the first form that the `querySelector` function comes across. We use `addEventListener` to attach the event. When the submit button is clicked the function `formAddPlayer` will fire. Note that `formAddPlayer` is passed as a reference not as a function call.
4. The actual `formAddPlayer` function: the argument `e` refers to the event. In this case a *submit event*. The actual submitting is cancelled using `e.preventDefault()`. The we use `querySelector` on the form element (retrieved using the `target`, which is the `form`, of the *submit event*). We select the input element with the `name` : `name` and retrieve it's value using `value`. We pass this value to the method `addPlayer` of the instance `scorecard`.

Al together:

```js
function Scorecard() {
  this.players = 0;
  this.playerList = []; //create a new Array() using shorthand [];
  this.addPlayer = function(name) {
    this.players++; //add one to the player count.
    this.playerList.push(name); //add a player to the playerlist using array.push().
  }
};

var scorecard = new Scorecard(); //first create an instance of Scorecard

function formAddPlayer(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); //e is the submit event. preventDefault stops it from actually posting the form, causing the page to reload.
  var name = e.target.querySelector("input[name='name']").value //get the value from the input element.
  scorecard.addPlayer(name);

  //show the results
  alert("Player amount: " + scorecard.players + "\nPlayers: \n -" + scorecard.playerList.join("\n -")); //show the results
}
document.querySelector("form").addEventListener("submit", formAddPlayer, false);
```

```html
<section class="name1-2-12">
  <form class='name' >
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="NAME">
    <input type='submit' name='submit'>
  </form>
</section>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/55u2b81j/

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
var aScorecard = new Scorecard();

$('form.name').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $(this).children('input[name="name"]').val();
    aScorecard.addPlayer(name);
});
```